# Image not rendering inside Canvas using Shiny renderImage

Tags: r, canvas, shiny, fabricjs

I'm trying to use Fabric.js interactively in a Shiny app. Shiny should render the image, then the user will modify it via Fabric. Then, Shiny will read that image back in to the server and further process it. However, I can't get past the first step at the moment!

In the code below, the plot/png displays below the canvas, but not inside of it. Is how I reference the image id in the javascript wrong?

Maybe it is because the renderImage places the image inside a div?

Here's the code:

```
library(shiny)

js <- "
$(document).ready(function () {
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('drawarea'); 

var imgElement = document.getElementById('myimage');
var imgInstance = new fabric.Image(imgElement, {
  left: 100,
  top: 100,
  angle: 0,
  opacity: 0.75,
  width:300,
  height:300
});
canvas.add(imgInstance);   

});
"

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(tags$script(HTML(js))),
  tags$head(tags$script(src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.22/fabric.min.js", type="text/javascript")),
  tags$head(
    tags$style(HTML("
   canvas {
    border: 1px solid #999;
   }
    myimage{display:none;}

    "))
  ),
  
  titlePanel("Fabric Demo"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      h4("Side")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      
      HTML('
           <canvas width="800" height="800" id="drawarea" style="border: 1px solid red;float: right">     </canvas>
           '),
      plotOutput("div.for.image")
    )
  )
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {
 
   output$div.for.image <- renderImage({
     
    outfile <- tempfile(fileext='.png')
    
    # Generate a png
    png(outfile, width=400, height=400)
    hist(rnorm(20))
    dev.off()
    
    # Return a list
    list(src = outfile,
         alt = "This is alternate text",
         id = "myimage")
  }, deleteFile = TRUE)
  
    }

shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```

Comment: FYI, you can use [this R package](https://github.com/feddelegrand7/fabricerin) to do what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `shiny:value` JavaScript event, which is triggered when an output is rendered.

```
library(shiny)

js <- "
$(document).on('shiny:value', function(evt) {
  if(evt.name === 'divForImage') {
    setTimeout(function(){
      var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('drawarea'); 
      var imgElement = document.getElementById('myimage');
      var imgInstance = new fabric.Image(imgElement, {
        left: 100,
        top: 100,
        angle: 0,
        opacity: 0.75,
        width: 300,
        height: 300
      });
      canvas.add(imgInstance);
    }, 0);
  }
});
"

# ui #########
ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$script(
      src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.22/fabric.min.js"
    ),
    tags$script(HTML(js)),
    tags$style(HTML(
      "canvas {border: 1px solid #999;}
       #myimage{display:none;}"))
  ),
  
  titlePanel("Fabric Demo"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      h4("Side")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tags$canvas(
        width="800", height="800", id="drawarea", style="border: 1px solid red; float: right;"
      ),
      imageOutput("divForImage")
    )
  )
)

## server #######
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output[["divForImage"]] <- renderImage({
    
    outfile <- tempfile(fileext='.png')
    
    # Generate a png
    png(outfile, width=400, height=400)
    hist(rnorm(20))
    dev.off()
    
    # Return a list
    list(src = outfile,
         alt = "This is alternate text",
         id = "myimage")
  }, deleteFile = TRUE)
}

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

*Note:* don't use periods in ids, this can lead to some issues.

Answer (score 1):

You have to trigger the JavaScript code after the image has been inserted by Shiny. Right now you a re firing the code as soon as the document is ready.

I would use `shinyjs` for this task and use the `runjs` and `delay` function, to wait until the list with the image is returned and visible in the HTML.

If you want to hide the image rendered by Shiny you need an **#** in the css (like `#myimage`)

Full Code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

js <- "
$(document).ready(function () {
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('drawarea'); 

var imgElement = document.getElementById('myimage');
var imgInstance = new fabric.Image(imgElement, {
  left: 100,
  top: 100,
  angle: 0,
  opacity: 0.75,
  width:300,
  height:300
});
canvas.add(imgInstance);   

});
"

# ui #########
ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  tags$head(tags$script(src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.22/fabric.min.js", type="text/javascript")),
  tags$head(
    tags$style(HTML("canvas {border: 1px solid #999;}
    #myimage{display:none;}"))
  ),
  
  titlePanel("Fabric Demo"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      h4("Side")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      HTML('<canvas width="800" height="800" id="drawarea" style="border: 1px solid red;float: right"></canvas>'),
      plotOutput("div.for.image")
    )
  )
)

## server #######
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$div.for.image <- renderImage({
    
    outfile <- tempfile(fileext='.png')
    
    # Generate a png
    png(outfile, width=400, height=400)
    hist(rnorm(20))
    dev.off()
    
    delay(200, runjs(HTML(js)))
    
    # Return a list
    list(src = outfile,
         alt = "This is alternate text",
         id = "myimage")
  }, deleteFile = TRUE)
}

shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```

Comment: Thanks. I presume the delay value wouldn't always work -- is there a way to not rely on it?